# Which is the main clause and which the subclause in "as ... so ..." sentences?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, terminology, clauses, subordinate-clauses, correlative-conjunctions

In

> As their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes, so did their culture.

Is the main clause:

1. so did their culture
2. as their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes
3. their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes

If it is (1), how can that be parsed syntactically? It's missing the lexical verb.

How do "as ... so ..." constructions function syntactically?

Comment: [A sentence structure that confuses me: As ... so ....](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448090/a-sentence-structure-that-confuses-me-as-so) asks about the meaning. [Much as ... so ....structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546620/much-as-so-structure) doesn't have an answer as to structure.

Comment: *The harder you try, the luckier you get.*

Answer (score 1):

*Is the main clause: 1. so did their culture 2. as their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes 3. their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes*

#1 is correct. The first clause (before the comma) is introduced by the subordinating conjunction "as", so it must be a subordinate clause. The second clause (after the comma) begins with "so", which functions adverbially here, so it works as an independent clause. (The appropriate meanings of "as" and "so" are very easy to find in a dictionary, so I won't include them here.)

---

*If it is (1), how can that be parsed syntactically? It's missing the lexical verb.*

Lexical verbs are often omitted when repeated or otherwise understood; that is no problem. It should be obvious that the second clause omits "to move".

---

*How do "as ... so ..." constructions function syntactically?*

Answered above.

Comment: Which verb is _so_  modifying?

Comment: @theonlygusti Whyever would one of a pair of clause connectors have to "modify" a "verb"? ***As** a dog returns to its vomit, **so** a fool repeats his folly.*

Comment: @tchrist what does it mean to say that a clause connector is functioning adverbially?

Comment: @theonlygusti It means that it operates on the the entire clause as a single syntactic constituent. ***If** you have something to say, **then** you should say it.* This is about syntax not about single words.

Comment: @tchrist then I think it's not an adverb but a regular conjunction right?

Comment: @theonlygusti In the traditional analysis for such correlative pairs as these, yes. But we're now getting into "fuzzy" word classes, some little more than junk yards into which have been randomly tossed all sorts of disparate items which do not all pattern the same as one another. The elusive borderline between adverbs and conjunctive adverbs and conjunctions and subordinators and prepositions can be remarkably tough to pin down these days, when each syntactician seems bent on inventing his own personal set of word classes by drawing his own would-be delineations.

Comment: @tchrist You've made my Christmas. Well, no, somebody else did that, but you know what I mean :)

Comment: @theonlygusti If you like, you can think of "so" as modifying the verb "did" (or the omitted "move"). On the other hand, as tchrist says, it may be better thought of as a modifier of the entire clause than of a single word.

Answer (score 0):

So ([FARLEX](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/so))

> In the same way; likewise: You were on time, and so was I.
>
> For that reason; therefore:
>
> With the result or consequence that:

As their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes, so did their culture.

*Reconstructed*

As their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes, with the consequence that their culture also moved along their trade routes.

Which do you think is the main clause?

**Edit**: Another reconstruction

As their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes, likewise their culture also moved along their trade routes.

Which do you think is the main clause?

Comment: I don't think this is a correct reconstruction. Why wouldn't this kind of reconstruction, based on replacing "as", also be valid? _At the same time that their wares moved eastwards along their trade routes, their culture moved along these trade routes_ — seems to imply the opposite conclusion